# Resistance of a resistor - dividing infinitisimals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, calculus

Given a resistor with the shape of half a sphere with inner radius of $R$ and outer radius of $3R$.

The sphere has a conductivity of $\sigma(r)=\frac{\sigma_0 R}{r} $.

A current is inserted in the radial direction, calculate the total resistance.

[image]

So my solution was first to transform the conductivity into resistivity with $\rho=\frac{1}{\sigma} $ and so I got that: $$ \rho(r)=\frac{r}{\sigma_0R} $$

Next, I wanted to divide the sphere into small lines, where each of them is a resistor that sums the resistance as a series. later on I want to sum them all as parallel.
I will mark $ N $ for resistance in this question.

Using  $N=\frac{\rho \cdot l}{A}\, \text{with} \, A=r^2\sin \theta d\phi d\theta $
to calculate every small resistor as a series we get $$ dN_{i}=\int\limits _{R}^{3R}\frac{r}{\sigma_{0}R}\frac{dr}{A}=\int\limits _{R}^{3R}\frac{rdr}{\sigma_{0}Rr^{2}\sin\left(\theta\right)d\phi d\theta}=\frac{1}{\sigma_{0}R\sin\theta d\phi d\theta}\int\limits _{R}^{3R}\frac{1}{r}dr=\frac{\ln r\biggl|_{R}^{3R}}{\sigma_{0}R\sin\theta d\phi d\theta}=\frac{\ln\left(3\right)}{\sigma_{0}R\sin\theta d\phi d\theta}. $$

Now I want to sum them all as parallel, so I will need to flip the whole expression and sum it with $ 0<\phi<2\pi $ and also $ 0<\theta <\frac{\pi}{2} $
This leads us to : $$ \frac{1}{N_{T}}=\frac{1}{N_{1}}+\frac{1}{N_{2}}+\dots\frac{1}{N_{n}}=\int\limits _{S}\frac{1}{\frac{\ln\left(3\right)}{\sigma_{0}R\sin\theta d\phi d\theta}}=\int\limits _{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits _{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sigma_{0}R\sin\theta d\phi d\theta}{\ln\left(3\right)}=\frac{2\pi R\sigma_{0}}{\ln3}\Rightarrow N_{t}=\frac{\ln\left(3\right)}{2\pi R\sigma_{0}}. $$
Is this the correct method to answer these types of questions?
I'm not sure if 'flipping' expressions with $ dx $ in the denominator are even allowed, would appreciate any feedback on this answer.
(This is the right answer, but I'm not sure if the math applied makes any sense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct, but I wouldn't call it efficient.

When you divide it in lines, they are not actually lines. They are *sectors*, meaning that their thickness on the outer side of the shell is greater than their thickness on the inner side. You have fixed this by using spherical system of coordinates.

I would calculate resistors as hemi-spherical-shells and sum them up as series. In this case
$$
dRes = \rho \frac{dr}{4\pi r^2 / 2} = \frac{1}{2 \sigma_{0} \pi R}\frac{dr}{r},
$$
where $\rho$ is the resistivity and $r$ is the radius you calculate it on. Basically thickness over area of the tiny resistor. Then integrate it from $R_{inner}$ to $R_{outer}$  and you get
$$
Res = \frac{\ln{3}}{\sigma_{0} 2 \pi R}
$$

The same answer, but seems to be simpler.

**UPD**: oh wait, the answer differs. Let me check who has the mistake.

**UPD2**: That's my mistake, I've accidentaly took the area of a circle ($\pi r^2$), not the spherical shell ($4 \pi r^2$). Fixed it.